# Accessing a multidimensial array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array below and I need to access the checkbox3 array and find out if it is set.

Something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<?php if(isset($fields['checkbox3']["One"])): ?>
    One is set
<?php endif; ?>

array(2) {
  ["checkbox2"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Don't Show"
  }
  ["checkbox3"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "One"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Three"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Four"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "Five"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
in_array("One", $fields["checkbox3"]);
```

Use [in_array().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict ] )
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, you got it right quickest, so I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 2):

`$fields['checkbox3']["One"]` doesn't exist, rather `"One"` is the value of `$fields['checkbox3'][0]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) function for that:

```
if (in_array("One", $fields["checkbox3"])) {
```

It looks up if a string exists as entry in the array. So you don't have to know the index or traverse the array yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(isset($fields['checkbox3'][0])): ?>
    One is set
<?php endif; ?>
```

or use

[in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, the array size will fluctuate